# How to get a hash from another hash if keys are present in an array

Tags: ruby

I have a hash, say:

```
hash1 ={1=>"a",2=>"b",3=>"c",4=>"d"}
```

and an array, say:

```
arr=[2,3]
```

and I have to find a resultant hash like:

```
hash2={2="b",3=>"c"}
```

That is, the resultant hash must contain only those key-value pairs whose keys are present in the given array. Is it possible to do this without a loop?

Comment: Re: "without any loop": Why can't you use a loop?

Comment: @ruakh - I'm guessing it's because a loop seems overly verbose for a simple task like this. (It seems like there should be a more concise syntax in a high-level language like Ruby.)

Answer (score 7):

The following will do what you want but is destructive to the original `hash1`.

```
hash2 = hash1.keep_if {|k,v| arr.include? k}
```

The following will do what you want but keeps `hash1` as it originally was.

```
hash2 = hash1.select {|k,v| arr.include? k}
```

Comment: This will alter `hash1`, it will delete all other key value pairs. Insert a `dup` to prevent this.

Comment: Good point, this does alter hash1. As pointed out in another answer using select will do the same but less destructive.

Comment: Thats true, using `select` is better than using `dup.keep_if` if you need it. For some applications, it may well be useful to alter the original array.

Answer (score 4):

```
  hash1.select {|k,v| arr.member? k}  # {2=>"b", 3=>"c"}
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution and does not alter the original hash, so for me this sounds like the best. +1

Comment: I will go also with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
1.9.3p392 :001 > hash1 ={1=>"a",2=>"b",3=>"c",4=>"d"}
 => {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"d"} 
1.9.3p392 :002 > arr=[2,3]
 => [2, 3] 
1.9.3p392 :003 > hash2 = hash1.keep_if{|key, value| arr.include?(key)}
 => {2=>"b", 3=>"c"}
```

I know you said no loop, but this is as much close as I could get

Comment: Same here: This will alter hash1, it will delete all other key value pairs. Insert a `dup` to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmark for all answers so far:

```
require 'fruity'

hash1 = Hash[[*1..10000].zip[*1.10000]]
arr   = 1.upto(1000).select(&:odd?)

compare do
  keep_if_include do
    hash2 = hash1.dup.keep_if {|k,v| arr.include? k}
  end

  values_at_zip do
    hash2 = Hash[arr.zip(hash1.dup.values_at(*arr))]
  end

  select_member do
    hash2 = hash1.dup.select {|k,v| arr.member? k}
  end
end
```

Results:

```
Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 17 seconds.
select_member is faster than keep_if_include by 2x ± 0.1
keep_if_include is faster than values_at_zip by 410x ± 100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using rails, try

```
hash2 = hash1.sliec(*arr)
```

if you are just using ruby, try this

```
hash2 = hash1.select {|k, v| arr.include?(k) }
```